# How do I create a closure that takes either u32 or &str and returns u32 or usize respectively?

Tags: generics, struct, rust, traits

This is from chapter 13.1 of the Rust book, where we use closures, memoization and generic types. In this example I can already pass two different closures to the struct (`Cacher`) and get the values accordingly, but they have two be two different instances of the struct in order to handle the types correctly.

Can I build a generic type so the same instance of the struct can handle receiving either type and give me the value accordingly? Either the same `u32` I passed, or the length of the `&str` I passed.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let simulated_user_specified_value = 10;
    let simulated_random_number = 7;

    generate_workout(simulated_user_specified_value, simulated_random_number);
}

fn generate_workout(intensity: u32, random_number: u32) {
    let mut expensive_result = Cacher::new(|num| {
        println!("calculating slowly...");
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
        num
    });

    if intensity < 25 {
        println!("Today, do {} pushups!", expensive_result.value(intensity));
        println!("Next, do {} situps!", expensive_result.value(intensity));
    } else {
        if random_number == 3 {
            println!("Take a break today! Remember to stay hydrated!");
        } else {
            println!(
                "Today, run for {} minutes!",
                expensive_result.value(intensity)
            );
        }
    }
}

struct Cacher<T, U, V>
where
    T: Fn(U) -> V,
{
    calculation: T,
    values: HashMap<U, Option<V>>,
}

impl<T, U, V> Cacher<T, U, V>
// Generic T is the function where U and V are the parameter and return value respectively for said function.
where
    T: Fn(U) -> V,
    U: std::cmp::Eq // U must have 3 trait bounds, Eq, Hash, and Copy.
        + std::hash::Hash
        + Copy,
    V: Copy, // V must have trait bound Copy.
{
    fn new(calculation: T) -> Cacher<T, U, V> {
        Cacher {
            calculation,
            values: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    fn value(&mut self, arg: U) -> V {
        match self.values.get(&arg) {
            // Get the value for the key in the hashmap.
            Some(v) => v.unwrap(), // get the value in the option stored in the hashmap.
            None => {
                let v = (self.calculation)(arg);
                self.values.insert(arg, Some(v)); // Put the key/value pair into the hashmap.
                v
            }
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::Cacher;
    #[test]
    fn call_with_different_values() {
        let mut c = Cacher::new(|a| a);

        let _v1 = c.value(1);
        let v2 = c.value(2);

        assert_eq!(v2, 2);
    }

    #[test]
    fn call_with_string_usize() {
        let mut c = Cacher::new(|a: &str| a.len());

        let v1 = c.value("Three");

        assert_eq!(v1, 5);
    }
}
```

I tried building structs for the `value` field of the struct and then implementing a trait of that would group them:

```rust
struct CStr<'a> {
    value: &'a str,
}

struct CInt {
    value: u32,
}

trait CValue {
    fn get<W: Copy + Eq>(&self) -> W;
}

impl<'a> CValue for CStr<'a> {
    fn get<W: Copy + Eq>(&self) -> W {
        self.value.len()
    }
}
```

So this test would pass

```rust
#[test]
fn call_with_different_values() {
    let mut c = Cacher::new(|a| a.get());

    let v1 = c.value(1);
    let v2 = c.value("two");

    assert_eq!(v2, 3);
}
```

but I am stuck here:

```
impl<'a> CValue for CStr<'a> {
    fn get<W: Copy + Eq>(&self) -> W {
        self.value.len() // here
    }
}
```

with the error:

```
[rustc E0308] [E] mismatched types expected type parameter `W` found type `usize`
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're after here, but perhaps you want to add an [associated type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#specifying-placeholder-types-in-trait-definitions-with-associated-types) to the `CValue` trait (and its `get` method would then return an instance of that associated type)?  Then each implementation can specify what type it will return.

Comment: If you would like to support multiple return types for a given type (e.g. conversion to both a `usize` len and a `String` copy for `&str` ), you can move the `W` generic type parameter to the `CValue` trait instead of an associated type as @eggyal said.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste the exact and entire error that you're getting — that will help us to understand what the problem is so we can help best. Sometimes trying to interpret an error message is tricky and it's actually a different part of the error message that's important. Please use the message from running the compiler directly, not the message produced by an IDE, which might be trying to interpret the error for you.

Comment: In case it's not obvious how an associated type would work here, perhaps [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f822ccb7e3cf1174d77d3091cdbd70ec) will help.

Comment: It's great that you have the solution to your question! You should post it as an answer rather than an edit to your question and then potentially accept that answer. That way, the question shows up as solved in search results, people can vote on your answer, and your solution can be more helpful to future people with the same problem.

Comment: @Shepmaster I posted the edit as an answer, thanks for the tip and all you all for your comments.

Comment: Great! I've deleted the *answer* from the *question*, as well. Now you can choose to accept your own answer (maybe after waiting a while).

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using associated types, thanks to some comments.

Here is the working code that allows me to call the same `Cacher` instance with an input of either `&str` or `u32`. I  actually implemented two structs: `CStr` and `CInt` and both conform to the trait `CValue`. That allows me to pass either of them and use the `CValue::get()` method to get the value (either the same `u32` or the length of the `&str` as `u32`):

**main.rs**

```rust
use crate::closures::{CInt, CStr};

fn is_number(input: &str) -> bool {
    for c in input.chars() {
        println!("Aqui los chars: {}", c);
        if !c.is_numeric() {
            return false;
        }
    }
    true
}

fn main() {
    if is_number(&intensity) {
        let simulated_user_specified_value = CInt::new(intensity.parse::<u32>().unwrap());
        closures::generate_workout(simulated_user_specified_value, simulated_random_number);
    } else {
        let simulated_user_specified_value = CStr::new(&intensity);
        closures::generate_workout(simulated_user_specified_value, simulated_random_number);
    }
}
```

**lib.rs**

```rust
use std::{collections::HashMap, fmt::Display, hash::Hash, thread, time::Duration};

pub fn generate_workout<X: CValue<ItemOut = u32> + Copy + Eq + Hash>(
    intensity: X,
    random_number: u32,
) {
    let mut struct_clouse = Cacher::new(|num: X| {
        println!("calculating slowly...");
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(2));
        num.get()
    });

    if intensity.get() < 25 {
        println!("Today, do {} pushups!", struct_clouse.value(intensity));
        println!("Next, do {} situps!", struct_clouse.value(intensity));
    } else {
        if random_number == 3 {
            println!("Take a break today! Remember to stay hydrated!");
        } else {
            println!("Today, run for {} minutes!", struct_clouse.value(intensity));
        }
    }
}

pub struct Cacher<T, U, V>
where
    T: Fn(U) -> V,
{
    calculation: T,
    value: HashMap<U, V>,
}

impl<T, U, V> Cacher<T, U, V>
where
    T: Fn(U) -> V,
    U: Eq + Copy + Hash,
    V: PartialOrd + Copy,
{
    pub fn new(calculation: T) -> Cacher<T, U, V> {
        Cacher {
            calculation,
            value: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn value(&mut self, arg: U) -> V {
        match self.value.get(&arg) {
            Some(v) => *v,
            None => {
                let v = (self.calculation)(arg);
                self.value.insert(arg, v);
                v
            }
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone, Copy, Eq, Hash, PartialOrd)]
pub struct CStr<'a> {
    value: &'a str,
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone, Copy, Eq, Hash, PartialOrd)]
pub struct CInt {
    value: u32,
}

impl CInt {
    pub fn new(value: u32) -> CInt {
        CInt { value }
    }
}

pub trait CValue {
    type ItemOut: Display + PartialOrd + Copy;
    fn get(&self) -> Self::ItemOut;
}

impl<'a> CStr<'a> {
    pub fn new(value: &str) -> CStr {
        CStr { value }
    }
}

impl<'a> CValue for CStr<'a> {
    type ItemOut = u32;

    fn get(&self) -> Self::ItemOut {
        self.value.len() as Self::ItemOut
    }
}

impl CValue for CInt {
    type ItemOut = u32;

    fn get(&self) -> Self::ItemOut {
        self.value
    }
}
´´´
```